# Use arrays and if or for loops and output separate files

Tags: arrays, powershell, parsing

My office gets text 7 text files with about 10,000 lines of text each 163 characters long. The string of text ends in zip codes either in 5 digit or 10 character strings (ex. xxxxx or xxxxx-xxxx). I am trying to write a script that will read the text files and output filtered text files into their mail distribution counties

I have taken one file and have been successful and getting an output of certain zips with this:

```
$content | Select-String -Pattern ".{153}006[0-9]{2,}"
```

I have set up arrays for each county with an empty array where non-ca zip codes will be sorted to reno. I haven't gotten as far as to put values into reno.

## Code

```
$LA = 900,901,902,903,904,905, 907, 908
$Industry = 906, 917, 918
$SantaClarita = 910,916
$SanDiego = 919,921
$SanBernardino= 922,925
$SantaAna = 926,927
$Anaheim = 928
$SantaBarbara = 930, 931, 934
$Bakersfield = 932, 933, 935
$Fresno = 936, 937, 938
$SanJose = 939, 950, 951
$SanFrancisco = 940, 941, 943, 944, 949, 954
$Sacramento = 942, 952, 953, 956, 957,958,959
$Oakland = 945..948
$Eureka = 955
$Redding = 960
[String]$Reno = @()

<#put values into $Reno
if (values are not in $zipcodes){$reno = $_}

Please excuse the formatting#>
```

I would like the script to flow like

```
$content = get-content -path .\*txt

if ($content | Select-String -Pattern ".{153}$LA[0-9]{2,}")
      {
      out-file -path .$LA.txt
      }
```

so on and so forth and values not found in move to reno.txt

Output Text:

```
<153 Characters>xxxxx     
<153 Characters>xxxxx-xxxx
```

## Input Lines

```
123456          92345555                                                                2570 S Fake St    AVE                       280SNO                      CA  93725-1724
123456          92345555                                                                2560 S Fake St    AVE                       280SNO                      CA  93725-1124
```

Comment: can you add a few lines of one of the input files to your Original Post?

Comment: Your approach with named arrays doesn't make sense to me, build a hash table with the codes as key and their mail distribution counties as value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel like this could be better served by creating a hashtable to track what city each code goes to, then using that as a lookup. Then you could use a capture group, and reference that to the hashtable, and be done with it.

```
$CityHT = @{}
900,901,902,903,904,905, 907, 908 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"LA.txt")}
906, 917, 918 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"Industry.txt")}
910,916 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"SantaClarita.txt")}
919,921 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"SanDiego.txt")}
922,925 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"SanBernardino.txt")}
926,927 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"SantaAna.txt")}
928 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"Anaheim.txt")}
930, 931, 934 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"SantaBarbara.txt")}
932, 933, 935 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"Bakersfield.txt")}
936, 937, 938 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"Fresno.txt")}
939, 950, 951 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"SanJose.txt")}
940, 941, 943, 944, 949, 954 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"SanFrancisco.txt")}
942, 952, 953, 956, 957,958,959 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"Sacramento.txt")}
945..948 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"Oakland.txt")}
955 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"Eureka.txt")}
960 | %{$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"Redding.txt")}
```

That leaves you with a hashtable that will match those numbers (in string form) to an output file. Then you just need to add anything that goes to Reno. You can use the matches that are automatically generated by `Select-String` to do that.

```
#Get content and perform matching
$Content = Select-String -Path "*.txt" -Pattern ".{153}(\d{3})[0-9]{2,}"
#Add extra codes to Reno
$Content.Matches.Groups.Captures|?{$_.Name -eq '1' -and $_.Value -notin $CityHT.Keys}|Select -ExpandProperty Value -Unique|ForEach-Object{$CityHT.Add($_,"Reno.txt")}
#Add content to files by matches
$Content|ForEach{Add-Content -Value $_.Line -path $CityHT[$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value]}
```

**Edit:** Ok, I just tested this against multiple files and made a revision to make it work with multiple files. Now, as requested, let's break the second codeblock down. The first thing we do is look for matching patterns in your files. The `Select-String` cmdlet allows you to specify a path, wildcards accepted, in which it will attempt to perform the string matching. So rather then reading in the whole files, then piping that against `Select-String` I just do it in one step. What `Select-String` outputs is more than just the lines that match, it also outputs matching information for each line. I slightly modified your RegEx pattern to include a capture group, so it now captures the three digits we care about as part of the output. If you just output it to screen it only shows you the source file, line number, and line text, but there's more there than that. Let's look at a single entry piped to `Format-List`:

```
IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 1
Line       : 123456          92345555                                                                2570 S Fake St    AVE                       280SNO                      CA  93725-1724
Filename   : datain.txt
Path       : C:\temp\datain.txt
Pattern    : .{153}(\d{3})[0-9]{2,}
Context    : 
Matches    : {0}
```

Now, each line that matched the pattern has an entry like this. Due to how matches are handled the `Matches` property will contains a `Groups` property with at least 1 entry, and 1 additional entry for each capturing group that the regular expression had (in our case only 1 capturing group). So when I reference `.Matches.Groups[1].Value` I can get that line's 3 digit code that was in the capturing group.

I use that in the next line, where I loop through all of the entries in `$Content`, checking if that 3 digit code already has a record in the hashtable that we created earlier, and if it is already in there I filter it out passing only codes that aren't accounted for down the pipeline with this bit of code:

```
$Content.Matches.Groups.Captures|?{$_.Name -eq '1' -and $_.Value -notin $CityHT.Keys}
```

That could pass a lot of 3 digit codes down the pipeline, many of which I suspect would be duplicates, so I pass it to `|Select -Unique` to only get unique 3 digit codes. Those I add to the hashtable and assign to Reno.txt, so anything not defined in the first section automatically goes to Reno.

Now, for the last line... I pass `$Content` into a loop and use `Add-Content` to write each line to a path based on the captured value. We have a hashtable that will convert a 3 digit code into a filename for the associated city, so I just reference that to determine which file to write each line to.

Comment: I am still getting my feet wet in powershell. could you help break down your second code block?
``$Content = Select-String -Path "*.txt" -Pattern ".{153}(\d{3})[0-9]{2,}"``
This is creating an array of what is in the specified file(s) and match the pattern.
``$Content|Where-Object{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.ToString() -notin $CityHT.Keys}|Select-Object -Unique|ForEach-Object{$CityHT.Add($_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.ToString(),"Reno.txt")}
Piping $content we look for values not in the hashtable, then find the unique ones, putting the values into Reno Hash

my big question is how to output

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code I had there, since it didn't work with multiple files, and added in explanations. Please let me know if something needs further clarification.

Comment: Thank you TheMadTechnician!

Comment: Last question, do I need the city txt files in the path I am pulling the input from? or how or where are the city txt files created?

Comment: You could create them anywhere you want. Rather than just a file name put a full path. For example, change `$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"LA.txt")` to `$CityHT.Add($_.ToString(),"C:\CityFiles\LA.txt")`